# Automatic download and installation of Visual Studio Redistributable

Tags: wix

My SW project depends on Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015.
If the Redistributable is not installed on a target machine, I would like to download it from the Internet and install it during installation of my project.
Is it possible to do using Wix installer?
I prefer not to use merge modules and include the Redistributable to the my application installer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using a bundle. See http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet.html for how it's done with .NET. For VC redistributables, you'd need to define your own [`ExePackage`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/exepackage.html) for vcredist_x86.exe or vcredist_x64.exe.